# SQL double aggregate function with condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I have one table which looks like fallowing.

```
DepartmentId    | Salary  | Status       
----------------------------------
1               |  5     | active
1               |  10     | active
1               |  15     | passive
1               |  20     | passive
```

I want to select this table with fallowing output.

```
Columns:
DepartmentId,
Sum of salary where status is active ,
Sum of salary where status is passive.


DepartmentId    | Sum(salary) where status is active  | Sum(salary) where status is passive       

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1           |  15                                 | 35
```

I am using postgresql as database.
How can i query the table to get output as upper ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select
    departmentid,
    sum(case status when 'active' then salary else 0 end) as active_salary_sum,
    sum(case status when 'passive' then salary else 0 end) as passive_salary_sum
from t
group by departmentid
```

Answer (score 3):

Its pretty simple, do you want an optimization in this or you want us to write query for you?

```
Select DepartmentId,
Sum (case when status='active' then salary end) as SumOfActive ,
Sum (case when status='passive' then salary end) as SumOfPassive
From TableName
Group By DepartmentId
```

Comment: "or you want us to write query for you?" Ha! I'm pretty sure this was a 'write the codez for meh!' question.  Good first (or 3rd) answer...welcome to SO and keep it up

Comment: Sorry Dude, At first i have chosen wrong title to my question, I think this query is enough optimal for me. Thanks for your answer.